# Entity Framework 6 Detect new Entity

Tags: entity-framework

In entity framework 4 I could check the EntityKey of an Entity and if it was null I new I had a new entity rather than an existing, detached entity.

How can I tell if an entity is new in Entity framework 6?

Comment: You should be able to do the same in EF6. You could also check what state the entity is in (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry.state(v=vs.113).aspx) a newly added entity will be in the `Added` state.

Comment: The entities don't have an EntityKey property that I can see

Comment: You can't get the `EntityKey` directly but you can drop to `ObjectContext` as follows: `((IObjectContextAdapter)myDbContext).ObjectContext` and then you can use old APIs as you used to. `DbContext` is however more streamlined and preferred way to work with EF these days.

Comment: How would you use the DBContext to detect a new entity?

Comment: Try:
`var entry = myDbContext.Entry(myEntity);
 var isNewEntity = entry != null && entry.State == EntityState.Added;
`
I think `.Entry()` returns null if the object you are passing is not tracked by EF.

Comment: If you put that as an answer I'll try it out and mark it as answer if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the context to look at the database to see if the entity is in the database.

Answer (score 0):

In EF6 you can get `EntityKey` by dropping down to the `ObjectContext`:

```
(((IObjectContextAdapter)myDbContext).ObjectContext)
    .ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entity).EntityKey
```

Comment: This is actually incorrect, it does not return null, but returns a detached entity.

Comment: In that case `entry.State == EntityState.Added` should be enough. I updated the post.

Comment: no, it shows up as EntityState.Detached, so I can't tell if it's new from the state either

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. I looked into this a bit more and I don't think you can get `EntityKey` without dropping down to `ObjectContext`.